# MVC How to dynamically add a new row

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having a web page where I can edit rows of data. I can edit some, delete some, click a "save all" button and everything goes fine.

I'm now willing to allow adding new "empty and ready for edition" rows.

When I learned how to delete rows, I understood the importance of indexing properly the inputs' names (ex: `name="[0].Price"`).

I wonder what's the preferred/best way to handle those for rows' addition.

I'm confident this question must have been asked already, but I couldn't find answer (did I poorly pick the keywords I googled with?).

---

```
<form action="/en-GB/MemberField" id="ca4b358f-0510-42a1-9d5f-4480451769ac" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="Jbczos1wMnFXNCvqZeiExYDIK1EZa8gqA_zI9e8Ajd0ykpMxgl9S4telkqGLJVfpucIgJNd7yqoBGLnHccBizDbraQ5ucdWu-_akJhM857Y1" />    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                System?
            </th>
            <th>
                Virtual?
            </th>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
    <td>
        <input checked="checked" class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input checked="checked" class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Virtual? field is required." name="[0].IsVirtual" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[0].IsVirtual" type="hidden" value="false" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input data-indexed="true" name="[0].Name" type="text" value="test 1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="delete" data-code="delete" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input checked="checked" class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input checked="checked" class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Virtual? field is required." name="[1].IsVirtual" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[1].IsVirtual" type="hidden" value="false" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input data-indexed="true" name="[1].Name" type="text" value="test 2" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="delete" data-code="delete" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input checked="checked" class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input checked="checked" class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Virtual? field is required." name="[2].IsVirtual" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[2].IsVirtual" type="hidden" value="false" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input data-indexed="true" name="[2].Name" type="text" value="test 5" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="delete" data-code="delete" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input checked="checked" class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Virtual? field is required." name="[3].IsVirtual" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[3].IsVirtual" type="hidden" value="false" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input data-indexed="true" name="[3].Name" type="text" value="test 3" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="delete" data-code="delete" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Virtual? field is required." name="[4].IsVirtual" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="[4].IsVirtual" type="hidden" value="false" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input data-indexed="true" name="[4].Name" type="text" value="test 4" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="delete" data-code="delete" />
    </td>
</tr>


    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="save"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var form = $('#ca4b358f-0510-42a1-9d5f-4480451769ac');

        form.find('[data-code="delete"]').click(function (evt) {
            var row = $(evt.target).closest('TR');

            row.remove();
        });

        form.bind('submit', function (evt) {
            // Code that handle indexing...
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: At-least show your generated HTML, add using jquery or mvc?

Comment: Jquery or mvc: I'd rather avoid ajax if possible but it's actually more about whichever is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What works for me is to use a javascript function to add the new row. You have to keep the index of your model sequential, 0,1,2,3.... Something like this;

```
var iRowCnt = '@Model.Count()';

function AddRow()
{
  //Add your html fields using iRowCnt as the index
  var myRow = '<tr>'
    + '<td>'<input name="[' + iRowCnt + '].Name" type="text" value="" /></td>'
    + '</tr>';
  $('#divSection').append(myRow);
  iRowCnt++;
}
```

Also, you'll need to link to a jquery library to use my example.